# SQL Server update value if previous value is not null

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table with 60 million records so I'm having trouble writing an update that doesn't take many hours.  Here's what the table looks like:

```
ID   Date
 1. 2016-05-12
 2. NULL
 3. 2016-09-17
 4. NULL
 5. NULL
 6. 2016-07-08
```

What I'm trying to do is update NULLs with the previous value if it's not null.  Unfortunately, everything I've written takes many hours.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you format the table as an actual table? What are these numbers? Are they a column?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: why would you test against all 60 million records?  why not create a similar database with a dozen rows that have all the values needed to exercise  your various test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, updates on a large amount of data can take a long time.  Unfortunately, in SQL Server 2008, you don't have `lag()`, so you can try an update like this:

```
update t
    set date = tt.date
    from table t cross apply
         (select top 1 t2.date
          from table t2
          where t2.id < t.id and t2.date is not null
          order by t2.id desc
         ) tt
    where t.date is null;
```

However, this has an optimization problem, which you can get around with a computed column and index:

```
alter table t add IsDateNull as (case when date is null then 1 else 0 end);

create index idx_t_IsDateNull_id on t(IsDateNull, id);
```

Then write this query as:

```
update t
    set date = tt.date
    from table t cross apply
         (select top 1 t2.date
          from table t2
          where t2.id < t.id and IsDateNull = 0
          order by t2.id desc
         ) tt
    where t.date is null;
```

Comment: The above sounds about right, but I ran this last night, and it's still going on 8 hours.  Seems really long for something so simple....not sure why this is still taking so long?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via aggregates,see below example

```
create table #test
(
id int,
datee date
)

select * from #test order by id desc

Output:
id  datee
1   2014-07-08
2   NULL
3   2015-09-13
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   NULL
```

--now you can use below query to update

```
update #test
set datee=(select min(datee) from #test t2 where t1.id<=t2.id)
from #test t1
```

Optimal index for below qquery is

```
create index nci_test1 on #test(id)
include(datee)
```